# postgres doesn't autogenerate PK if the PK is inserted manually

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myval
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('myval_myval_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(255),
    CONSTRAINT "PK_aa671c3359a0359082a84ecb801" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

the sequence definition is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS myval_myval_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 2147483647
    CACHE 1
    OWNED BY myval.myval_id;
```

when I insert data along with the primary key:

```
INSERT INTO myval(id, name) VALUES (1, 'sdf');
INSERT INTO myval(id, name) VALUES (2, 'sdf');
INSERT INTO myval(id, name) VALUES (3, 'sdf');
INSERT INTO myval(id, name) VALUES (4, 'sdf');
```

then, I insert it without the PK:

```
INSERT INTO myval(name) VALUES ('new sdf');
```

it gives an error saying:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_aa671c3359a0359082a84ecb801",
> DETAIL:  Key (myval_id)=(1) already exists.

I expected it to start with PK value of 5 but, instead it gives an error. Can we configure postgres to skip conflicting values and generate from the closest available value to use instead of throwing an error?

Comment: I believe the safest way would be not to allow clients to manually insert PKs in the first place. Perhaps an `identity column` is what you're looking for

Comment: That's one of the reasons `generated always as identity` is recommended this approach (which is the same as using a `serial`) because it will result in an error if you try to bypass the ID generation in the database

Comment: To answer you explicit question: no, that is not possible. Avoid overriding the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avoid such conflicts is to use identity columns - in this case a `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` seems the right option.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myval
(
    id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name character varying(255),
    CONSTRAINT "PK_aa671c3359a0359082a84ecb801" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

This will work like a sequence (serial), however it will fail if the user tries to manually insert a value in this column

```
INSERT INTO myval (id,name) 
VALUES (1,'foor');

ERROR:  cannot insert a non-DEFAULT value into column "id"
DETAIL:  Column "id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
TIP:  Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override.
```

If for whatever reason you must override this behavior in a certain `INSERT` statement you can do so using `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE`, as the error message above suggests

```
INSERT INTO myval (id,name) OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE
VALUES (1,'foo');
```

You might be able to achieve a sequential value using `serial` even if the user screws things up with inserts, e.g. using trigger functions. But such an architecture is hard to maintain and imho is definitely not worth the trouble.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d41d7015eb94859949b46b6dea6bf1ec)